# The ValidateAuthenticationStateAsync in the PersistingRevalidatingAuthenticationStateProvider in original Blazor 8 Identity template is never called

Tags: blazor-server-side

I examined the original Blazor 8 Identity template. Authentication is normally working, but the ValidateAuthenticationStateAsync method in the PersistingRevalidatingAuthenticationStateProvider class is never called.

```
internal sealed class PersistingRevalidatingAuthenticationStateProvider : RevalidatingServerAuthenticationStateProvider
{
private readonly IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory;
private readonly PersistentComponentState state;
private readonly IdentityOptions options;

private readonly PersistingComponentStateSubscription subscription;

private Task<AuthenticationState>? authenticationStateTask;

public PersistingRevalidatingAuthenticationStateProvider(
    ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
    IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory,
    PersistentComponentState persistentComponentState,
    IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor)
    : base(loggerFactory)
{
    scopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
    state = persistentComponentState;
    options = optionsAccessor.Value;

    AuthenticationStateChanged += OnAuthenticationStateChanged;
    subscription = state.RegisterOnPersisting(OnPersistingAsync, RenderMode.InteractiveWebAssembly);
}

protected override TimeSpan RevalidationInterval => TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
```

If we change revalidation time to 30 seconds:

```
protected override TimeSpan RevalidationInterval => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
```

we notice that the ValidateAuthenticationStateAsync method is never called.

```
protected override async Task<bool> ValidateAuthenticationStateAsync(
AuthenticationState authenticationState, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    await using var scope = scopeFactory.CreateAsyncScope();
    var userManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
    return await ValidateSecurityStampAsync(userManager, authenticationState.User);
}
```

We can also delete Cookie in application and nothing happens.
In Blazor 7, the method ValidateAuthenticationStateAsync is periodically called as expected.

Thanks for help in advance!